# Complexity of dynamic card game algorithm

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, probability-theory, recursion

Consider the following dynamic card game with a regular deck of 26 red cards and 26 black cards. A dealer draws the unturned cards one by one, and we can ask him to stop at any time. For every red card drawn, we get 1 dollar and lose 1 dollar for every black card drawn. The problem consists in finding an algorithm which returns the expected value of the game. If we denote by $b$ and $r$, respectively, the number of black and red cards left in the deck at any time, the expected value of the game $E(b,r)$ satisfies:

$$E(b,r)=\max\left\{b-r,\frac{b}{b+r}\,E(b-1,r)+\frac{r}{b+r}\,E(b,r-1)\right\}\,,$$

with boundary conditions $E(0,r)=0$ and $E(b,0)=b$. The expected value of the game is therefore given by $E(26,26)$.

My question is, if we implement the recursive algorithm associated with the above formula, how can we determine its complexity? Using the trivial cases of $E(1,1)$ and $E(2,2)$, it would appear that we are dealing with exponential complexity, but is there a way to prove this properly, and if so, what is the number of necessary operations to compute $E(n,n)$ for an arbitrarily large integer $n$? Any ideas or references to literature would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is "For every red ... black card drawn." when the red card is drawn or when we ask him to stop? ​ ​

Comment: Hint: use memoization.

Comment: Your recurrence is wrong. Even your boundary conditions are wrong (switch black and red). Start with fixing your recurrence.

Comment: The answer I get is 41984711742427/15997372030584.

Comment: @G.Bach When there's only black left you want to stop, so $E(b,0) = 0$. When there's only red left you want to take all of them, so $E(0,r) = r$. I am measuring payoff; what are you measuring?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I was doing it wrong, and now get the same as you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, your recurrence is wrong (though equivalent for $b=r$; it's a recurrence for $E(b,r)+b-r$). Also, you can solve this efficiently using memoization or its more principled cousin, dynamic programming. The dynamic programming solution calculates iteratively $E(i,j)$ for $i+j=0,1,\ldots,52$.

Finally, to answer your question, if you implement you original solution, you get a running time satisfying the recurrence
$$
T(b,r) = C + T(b-1,r) + T(b,r-1),
$$
with initial conditions $T(b,0) = O(1)$, $T(0,r) = O(1)$. If $T'(b,r) = T(b,r)-C$ then
$$
T'(b,r) = T'(b-1,r) + T'(b,r-1),
$$
a recurrence solved by $\alpha \binom{b+r}{r}$. Taking the initial conditions into account, we get that
$$
T(b,r) = \Theta\left(\binom{b+r}{r}\right).
$$
In particular,
$$
T(n,n) = \Theta\left(\binom{2n}{n}\right) = \Theta\left(\frac{4^n}{\sqrt{n}}\right).
$$
(This assumes all arithmetic is $O(1)$. The running time is actually somewhat larger since the relevant numbers grow fast, but this is a (multiplicative) lower-order factor.)

Comment: My recurrence and boundary conditions are perfectly correct. If there are no black cards left, it means we've already turned every black card. So the best we can do is turn over every red card to get our expected payoff to 0. If there are no red cards left, there are no remaining cards which can improve our score, which is equal to the number of outstanding black cards.

Comment: @user223935 I made the same thinko, but that's not how to go about this. $E(b,r)$ is independent of the values $E(b+c, r+d)$ for any $c,d>0$, or in words: the expected payoff for the remaining(!) game doesn't change, whether you already played a couple of rounds before it or not. At every step, you just optimize the expected payoff of the remaining game, not the overall game. That's why Yuval correctly says $E(0,r) = r$ and $E(b,0) = 0$ in a comment to your question.

Comment: @G.Bach With my boundary conditions and recurrence I find a value of 2.62 for E(26,26), which is perfectly consistent with known results about this game (see for example http://datagenetics.com/blog/october42014/index.html)

Comment: @G.Bach Also in the reference I mention, you just have to switch the red/black convention

Comment: @user223935 Let's put aside the question of correctness for a moment; are you still having trouble with running time, or did Raphael's hint help you?

Comment: I also get 2.62, so the site and me agree. I just wrote the exact expression, which is roughly 2.62.

Comment: I just implemented @user223935 's recurrence, and it also works out. Interesting.

Comment: It's probably a recurrence for $E(b,r)+b-r$. Check it out.

Comment: @G.Bach I just implemented the naive recursive formula and it took ages! I would be interested how it is possible to use memoization or dynamic programming in this case

Comment: @YuvalFilmus maybe a stupid question, but how exactly do you obtain the solution $\alpha \binom{b+r}{r}$ to the recursive equation in your answer?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Doesn't look like it - as you note it's correct when $b=r$, but for other values it diverges.

Comment: @user223935 As far as programming goes, this question should've been on SO, but since Yuval provided useful context and analysis, we should leave it here. As far as I'm concerned, you have put in effort and would be helped most by seeing an implementation, so here's [code](http://pastebin.com/MvHSzgAg). It's python 3.5 for the `math.isclose` function.

Comment: @user223935 Well, this is definitely one solution, using Pascal's identity. In the other direction, for proper boundary conditions you can probably show (by induction) that you obtain this exactly, and otherwise you can probably show that you get lower and upper bounds of this form.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Could you explain what the $\alpha$ is? I don't know that function.

Comment: @G.Bach isn't it just proportional?

Comment: @G.Bach It's not a function, just a constant. Any constant would work. It's a family of solutions.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Having a second look, $E(b,r) + b - r$ is right.

Comment: @G.Bach thanks for the code, very helpful

Comment: Anyway I think both recurrences are correct, it is just a matter of interpretation of expected value of a game/payoff, and the boundary conditions have to be adapted accordingly. In any case, the implementation of both recurrences gives the same final answer.

Comment: @G.Bach I just wanted to ask you one final thing regarding the code you provided: in the memoized version, my understanding is that the complexity is now quadratic as opposed to exponential, but is there a way to rigorously prove this?

Comment: @user223935 The table has size $\mathcal{O}(RB)$ where $R$ is the total number of red and $B$ the total number of black cards. Every cell in the table is accessed at most thrice: once to write into it, twice to calculate the two cells that rely on its value. Every access takes constant time, and if we assume arithmetic takes constant time, we are done with a time complexity of $\mathcal{O}(RB)$. That's as rigorous as proving time complexities gets, you just count how often each operation occurs and multiply it by the complexity of the operation.